# Missing argument arrayLiteral in call

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift2

I have a dictionary defined as:

```
var options: Dictionary <String, AnyObject>?
```

When I try to call

```
Array(options?.keys)
```

I get this error:

> **Missing argument label 'arrayLiteral:' in call**

How do I get the keys out of my dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Object constructors (i.e. `init()`s) in Swift require a name for each argument, so you need to call `Array(arrayLiteral: options?.keys)`. You probably have to unwrap the optional, though.

Comment: There are init methods with *empty* external parameter name as in this case, and I do not know any sensible case where you would use `arrayLiteral:` explicitly. – Your last sentence is correct though, i.e. `Array(options!.keys)`.

Comment: Martin R got it. NRitH, there's an additional error with the arrayLiteral .

Answer (score 1):

One answer is that you are passing it an optional value instead of a regular / non-optional value.

This works:

```
var options: Dictionary <String, AnyObject>?
Array(options!.keys)
```

There is more to this though.  In a separate case of my own, I have seen this error when creating a set from a literal array of custom objects, but only after I changed the custom object to not inherit from NSObject.

The plot thickens.